# Does the 2018-2019 US government shutdown affect travelling to and from the US?

Tags: usa, international-travel, event-based-effects

My grandparents bought a flight on United Airlines that departs on Feb 10 2019, as the one and same ticket, from Toronto, to ORD with 1 55-minute layover, then Maui. Please ping me if I ought post their return flight on Feb 24's details.  [This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/126309/13759) advises:

> There should be no customs and immigrations formalities at ORD, as YYZ is a [pre-clearance airport](https://www.torontopearson.com/Departing_to_usa.aspx#), and CBP matters will be handled in Toronto.

1. I'm assuming that [the 2018-2019 federal  gov't shutdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_federal_government_shutdown_of_2018%E2%80%932019) persists during their vacation to Maui.
2. [On Jan 11 2019, NY Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/01/11/nyregion/tsa-shutdown.html) reported some TSA agents' refusal to work.
3. Will [Air Traffic Controllers](https://www.washingtonpost.com/local/trafficandcommuting/air-traffic-controllers-get-their-first-shutdown-pay-stub-000/2019/01/10/080255e4-1525-11e9-b6ad-9cfd62dbb0a8_story.html?utm_term=.e9b7ebbfadb2) refuse to work, or any other federal workers pertinent to travelling to and from the US?

Comment: Pilots are trained to handle operating in and out of airports without controllers, though it is slower. The TSA/security thing is the bigger concern I think.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Umm.. no.  If ATC isn't working, planes aren't flying.  (Although ATC IS working)

Comment: Um, no. You're wrong, for the US at least. There are dozens of airports without ATC at all. Refer: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35576/how-do-airports-with-no-atc-operate?r=SearchResults I can't speak to non-US airports, though it's not really relevant to this situation. @Doc

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas So you think ORD airspace will just manage itself if there's no ATC? The answer you've linked to is relevant for small airports in the middle of nowhere. It is not in any sense of the word relevant to this question.

Comment: Yes, I do, because it's part of the training. There are 20,000 (ish) untowered airports in the US and 500 towered ones. And you *do* realize that 13,000 controllers went on strike in the early 80s? (Reagan fired close to 12,000 of them.) Aviation still happened, though flights were cancelled. Today's ATC is much more automated than it was then. LAX and other large airports would be a mess initially, with cancellations and reroutings, but aviation will still happen.

Comment: I found preclearance at YYZ to be incredibly slow this week (only 2-3 agents handling all non-visa nationals) so if the shutdown persists they should consider arriving at YYZ very early.

Comment: @KernelPanic Thanks a lot! I'll relay this to my grandparents.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, airliners fly under a different set of rules than general aviation.  Effectively, if there's no ATC, no airliners will fly.  (This is *especially* true for big, complicated airports like ORD.  Most of those 20,000 untowered airports are things like Ox Meadows or McWhorter Ranch: a thousand feet of mown grass, and maybe a shed to store the airplane in.)

Answer (score 9):

At this stage the impact from the US Government "Partial" Shutdown is minimal to zero for air travelers.

Staff such as TSA, CBP (including pre-clearance facilities such as in Toronto) and Air Traffic Control are all considered "essential employees" and thus are still working regardless of the partial shutdown, although they are not currently being paid (although they WILL be paid back-pay once the shutdown ends).

As you've pointed out, some TSA workers are "calling in sick", or in some cases even looking for new jobs, which is potentially leaving them a little short-staffed, however as this stage the impact of that has been at most minimal.  eg, Miami airport did close the "Terminal G" area early over this weekend, however that just resulted in flights that were due to use that terminal using a different one instead with no real traveler impact.

Air Traffic Control is still operating normally, and there haven't been any reports I've seen of this changing in the (near) future.

As time goes on the impact may increase, and it certainly wouldn't hurt for most travelers to arrive at the airport a little earlier than normal just in case.

Specifically for your parents, they will pass through Immigration/customs at Toronto airport, and will NOT need to re-clear security in Chicago so even if there are delays they will not be affected during transit.

**Update**: As the shutdown continues, there has been some impact at a small number of airports due to a shortage of TSA staff reporting to work. TSA is still reporting that the vast majority of passengers (93%) took less than 15 minutes to get through screening, and almost all (99.9%) are taking less than 30 mins, however there have been reports of a small number of airports having longer waits.  If flying, it would be best to check the news beforehand to get an idea if your airport is affected, and allow extra time to get through security just in case.

There have been significant flight delays/cancellations in certain locations over the past week or so, however these have been due to extremely cold weather and storms, and are not related to the government shutdown.

Comment: Atlanta is now being affected by the (lack of) TSA staff at check points

Answer (score 2):

I travel quite frequently between the US and Canada and the only impact I have seen is the NEXUS desk at YYZ (and assuming all other NEXUS enrollment centers), it is staffed by DHS/CBP officers and it is deemed non-essential.