# Pre-clearance and federal shut down

Tags: usa, international-travel, event-based-effects, pre-clearance, auh

Does anyone know how pre-clearance facilities at airports like Abu Dhabi are affected during US government shut downs? Still worth booking to go through those facilities in the next few days?

Comment: Duplicate of [Does the 2018-2019 US government shutdown affect travelling to and from the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130073/does-the-2018-2019-us-government-shutdown-affect-travelling-to-and-from-the-us)

Answer (score 3):

There is no change. All US ports of entry are open, including preclearance facilities.