# Will the US government shut down affect my 2hr stop-overs in LA and Atlanta?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, layovers, lax, atlanta

I am an Australian flying from Brisbane, Australia to Bogota, Colombia. I have 2 stop-overs en route on Saturday the 19th - one in LA, the next in Atlanta. Both are only 2hrs.

Because the flight from LA to Atlanta is domestic I must pass through customs and immigration in LA, then the reverse in Atlanta. I understand 2hrs is possible (I'm only taking carry-on luggage), but cutting it fine.

Should I be concerned that the US government shut down might create further delays?

Comment: Duplicate of [Does the 2018-2019 US government shutdown affect travelling to and from the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130073/does-the-2018-2019-us-government-shutdown-affect-travelling-to-and-from-the-us)

Comment: See the duplicate question for the general answer, but specifically, you will not have to pass through immigration or any sort of controls in Atlanta. You'll just go to your gate. All the terminals at Atlanta are connected behind security, and the US does not have exit immigration. You will have to go through immigration, customs, and security in LA.